# How to know which condition failed in a multiple condition typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, conditional-statements

I want to know which one of these conditions failed (if one of them fails)

What would be the ideal solution?

Code I'm using right now:

```js
const multiCondition =
  (await firstCondition()) &&
  (await secondCondition()) &&
  (await thirdCondition());

if (multiCondition) {
...
} else {
  // failed, (which one)???
}
```

Edit:

*Every condition is dependent from the previous one.*

Comment: does fail mean throw an error/reject the promise? or does it mean return false from firstCondition() etc?

Comment: every condition returns true or false, true meaning finished successfully and false failed.

Answer (score 1):

Right now all your promises execute serially. Is that intentional? If you want them all to execute in parallel, the easiest way to get the status of each is [`Promise.allSettled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled).

If you want them to run in serial, you could loop over all the conditions, and if it fails, short circuit and return the failure status for the rest of them. If they all succeed, it will just return an empty object.

```js
const conditions = [firstCondition, secondCondition, thirdCondition];

const result = await conditions.reduce(async (status, condition, index) => {
   // If we've already failed, don't run the current condition,
   // just return the failure status
   if(status.failed) {
     return status;
   }

   // Otherwise, run the condition..
   const test = await condition();

   // If it succeeded, return the accumulator, otherwise set the status
   // to failed, so the next runs will short circuit
   return test ? status : { failed: true, failedAt: index }
}, {});

if(result.failed) {
   console.log('condition failed: ', conditions[result.failedAt]);
}
```

And you can shorten the above code to something like

```js
const conditions = [firstCondition, secondCondition, thirdCondition];

const result = await conditions.reduce(async (status, condition, index) =>
  status.failed ?
  status :
  await condition() ?
  status :
  { failed: index },
  {}
);

if('failed' in result) {
   console.log('condition failed: ', conditions[result.failed]);
}
```

and then clean it up into a utility function:

```js
const promiseAnd = (...conditions) => await conditions.reduce(async (status, condition, index) =>
  status.failed ?
  status :
  await condition() ?
  status :
  { failed: index },
  {}
);

const { failed } = await promiseAnd(firstCondition, secondCondition, thirdCondition);
if(failed) {
  console.log(`Promise ${failed} failed`);
}
```

Comment: `reducer` seems to run all conditions in parallel and not `serially` demo here https://jsfiddle.net/ujxb2z8w/, maybe I got something wrong, correct me on that

Comment: I figured where the problem with your code was, you would need to also add `await status` otherwise it won't work, here's the fixed code https://jsfiddle.net/4koL8dpj/

Answer (score 0):

```
const cond1 = await firstCondition();
const cond2 = await secondCondition();
const cond3 = await thirdCondition();

const multiCondition =
  cond1 &&
  cond2 &&
  cond3;

if (multiCondition) {
...
} else {
  // failed, (which one)???
  // ?? cond1
  // ?? cond2
  // ?? cond3
}
```

Comment: This changes the execution order from the question. With this code, all promises execute, vs in the original, a failure will block the chain

Comment: Yeah this is not what i'm looking for because they are dependent from on another. As long as one of them fails the execution of the reset should not occur.

Answer (score 0):

The best way  would be to separate each condition in a diferent if.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I achieve this result:

```js
const conditions = [await firstCondition(), await secondCondition(), await thirdCondition()];

// check for all
const allConditions = conditions.reduce((cur, next) => cur && next);

if (allConditions) {
  // ok
} else {
  if (!conditions[0]) {
    // condition 0 failed
  } else if (!conditions[1]) {
    // condition 1 failed
  } else if (!conditions[2]) {
    // condition 2 failed
  } else {
    throw new Error('this should never happen');
  }
}
```

Comment: They need to be executed in a sequence, they're dependent from previous condition.

Answer (score 0):

If the intent is to exit the surrounding function I suggest using a guard clauses. Your async checks are already made in sequence, so you might as well do:

```
if (!await firstCondition()) {
  // firstCondition failed.
  return; // or throw
}

if (!await secondCondition()) {
  // second condition failed
  return; // or throw
}

if (!await thirdCondition()) {
  // third condition failed
  return; // or throw
}

// all results came back truthy
// ...
```

If you don't want to exit you can always use *else-if* statements instead.

```
if (!await thirdCondition()) {
  // first condition failed
} else if (!await secondCondition()) {
  // second condition failed
} else if (!await thirdCondition()) {
  // third condition failed
} else {
  // all results came back truthy
  // ...
}
```

Comment: The first on is not correct, but the second one is correct the way the conditions are, but you flipped the logic